# Trying to format text when pulling from webpage HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've created a basic counter for words in a song, but am having trouble formatting the album title and artist name from a given page on this lyrics website. Here's an example of what I am focused on:

[image: Sample HTML]

I want to format it in this way:

Album Title: [Album Title] (Release_year)

Artist: [Artist Name]

I'm running into two problems:

1. The album title isn't enclosed in its own tag, so if I call the h1 tag I get both the album name, release year and artist name. How do I call them separately, or how do I break them up when calling them?
2. The album name has two blank lines and two blank spaces included in the string. How do I get rid of them? The release year prints right next to the album title, which is exactly what I'm looking for, but I cant get the album title to format properly.

This is what I currently have:

```
song_artist = soup.find("a",{"class":"artist"}).get_text()
album_title = soup.find("h1",{"class":"album_name"}).get_text()
print "Album Title: " + str(album_title)
print "Song Artist: " + str(song_artist.title())
```

which produces:

[image: Current Output]

Thank you!!

Comment: post the code not the picture, this will save other people's time.

Comment: I did post the code? I figured posting a picture of the HTML would save people the time of following the link and posting a picture of the output would give a better idea of the space issue over copy+pasting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
album_title = soup.find("h1",{"class":"album_name"}).find(text=True).strip()
album_year = soup.find("span",{"class":"release_year"}).get_text().strip()

print 'Album Title: {} {}'.format(album_title, album_year)
```